# How to find my test Facebook Messenger App

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I have a FB Messenger app and created a test app for me to point at my development server (using ngrok for the webhook). As far as I can tell, everything is set up for me to be able to access the test app following the instructions here: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps

However, I can only find the public production version of my chatbot on my FB messenger app. How can I find the test version so that I can play around with my dev server?

Comment: Is your bot connected to a facebook page? If so, what happens if you message that page?

Comment: Yes,it hits my production server

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm having the same issue